# New TS3 server hosted on Ubuntu VPS - running, but failed to connect

Tags: vps, teamspeak

I have set up a new server on Ubuntu 20.04 (64bit) VPS following this tutorial: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-teamspeak-3-server/

Everything was right during the installation. The teamspeak.service is running (both systemctl service and the ts3 process "./ts3server inifile=ts3server.ini daemon=1 pid_file=ts3server.pid" are showing as running).

Server is ran by 'teamspeak' user and the folder belongs to him as well. 'ts3server.pid', '.ts3server_license_accepted', 'ts3server' and all other necessary files are present in '/home/teamspeak' folder.

Logs don't show any errors, only the licensekey.dat warning.

All required ports are open. Tried with disabled firewall. Tried with disabled firewall on my PC. Had a friend try to join. Nothing helps really. I ran tcpdump command listening to incoming connections on port 9987 - when I tried to join the server, it indeed received several udp packets coming from my IP.

Tried rebooting, restarting service, upgrading, autoremoving, cleaning. Is it rather issue related to my machine? Or is there something else I should check?

Comment: Does the hosting company you use have a firewall configuration outside of the VPS that needs to be configured? Amazon’s EC2 instances, for example, use Security Groups and no ports are wide open to the Internet without first being explicitly configured as such 

Comment: Not aware of any firewalls outside VPS. I'm using Contabo.

Comment: It's Ubuntu Linux 20.04.4, sorry for misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of this issue. I have Webmin+Virtualmin installed, and didn't realize it's **firewalld** package was installed and set up.

This did the trick for me:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=9987/udp
```